# Scrape ajax web page with python and/or scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

**What I want to do** is scrape petition data - name, city, state, date, signature number - from one or more petitions at petitions.whitehouse.gov

I assume at this point python is the way to go - probably the scrapy library - along with some functions to deal with the ajax aspects of the site. The reason for this scraper is that this petition data is not available to the public.

**I am a freelance tech journalist** and I want to be able to dump each petition's data into a CSV file in order to analyze the number of people from each state who sign a state's petition, and with data from multiple petitions, find the number of people who sign multiple petitions, etc., and then make some conclusions about the political viability of the petition process and the data itself.

The petition functions at petitions.whitehouse.gov run as a Drupal module, and the White House developers responded to my issue request on github https://github.com/WhiteHouse/petition/issues/44 that they are working on an API to allow access to petition data from the module. But there is no release date for that API; and that doesn't solve the problem of the petition data currently on petitions.whitehouse.gov.

**I've emailed the White House and the White House Developers**, stating that I am a freelance journalist and asking for some way to access to the data. The White House Office of Digital Strategy told me that *"Unfortunately, we don't have the means to provide data exports at this time, but we are working to open up the data going forward via the API."*
There is an "Open Data" initiative at the White House, but apparently petition data is not covered.

**Privacy and TOS:** There is little privacy expected in signing a petition. And no clear TOS that addresses web scraping of this data.

**What has been done:** Some faculty at UNC have written (what I assume is) a python script to scrape the data, but they don't want to release the script to me, saying they are still working on it. http://www.unc.edu/~ncaren/secessionists/ They did send me a CSV data dump of one petition I am particularly interested in.

**What I've done:** I've set up a github project for this, because I want any petition data scraper to be useful for everyone - petitioners themselves, journalists, etc. - who wants to be able to get this data. https://github.com/markratledge/whitehousescraper

*I have no experience with python and little experience with shell scripting, and what I'm trying to do is obviously beyond my experience at this point.*

I ran a GUI script to send a "spacebar" to the web browser every five seconds or so, and in that way scraped ~10,000 signatures by cutting and pasting the browser text into a text editor. From there, I could process the text with grep and awk into a CSV format. This, of course, doesn't work too well; Chrome bogged down with the size of the page, and it took hours to get that many signatures.

**What I've found so far:** from what I can gather from other SO questions and answers, it looks like Python and scrapy http://scrapy.org is the way to go to avoid problems with browsers. But the page uses an ajax function to load the next set of signatures. It appears that this is a "static" ajax request, because the URL doesn't change.

In Firebug, the JSON request headers appear to have a random string appended to them with a page number just before. Does this say anything towards what needs to be done? Does a script need to emulate and send these to the webserver?

> Request
>   URL:https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/signatures/more/50ab2aa8eab72abc4a000020/2/50b32771ee140f072e000001
>   Request
>   URL:https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/signatures/more/50ab2aa8eab72abc4a000020/3/50b1040f6ce61c837e000006
>   Request
>   URL:https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/signatures/more/50ab2aa8eab72abc4a000020/4/50afb3d7c988d47504000004

This is the JS function that loads the signatures on the page:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.morePetitions = {
  attach: function(context) {
    $('.petition-list .show-more-petitions-bar').unbind();
    $(".petition-list .show-more-petitions-bar").bind('click',
      function () {
        $('.show-more-petitions-bar').addClass('display-none');
        $('.loading-more-petitions-bar').removeClass('display-none');

        var petition_sort = retrieveSort();
        var petition_cols = retrieveCols();
        var petition_issues = retrieveIssues();
        var petition_search = retrieveSearch();
        var petition_page = parseInt($('#page-num').html());

        var url = "/petitions/more/"+petition_sort+"/"+(petition_page + 1)+"/"+petition_cols+"/"+petition_issues+"/"+petition_search+"/";
        var params = {};
        $.getJSON(url, params, function(data) {
          $('#petition-bars').remove();
          $('.loading-more-petitions-bar').addClass('display-none');
          $('.show-more-petitions-bar').removeClass('display-none');
          $(".petition-list .petitions").append(data.markup).show();

          if (typeof wh_petition_adjustHeight == 'function') {
            wh_petition_adjustHeight();
          }

          Drupal.attachBehaviors('.petition-list .show-more-petitions-bar');
          if (typeof wh_petition_page_update_links == 'function') {
            wh_petition_page_update_links();
          }
        });

        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and that is fired when this div is revealed when scrolling to the bottom of the browser window:

```
<a href="/petition/.../l76dWhwN?page=2&amp;last=50b3d98e7043012b24000011" class="load-next no-follow active" rel="509ec31cadfd958d58000005">Load Next 20 Signatures</a>
<div id="last-signature-id" class="display-none">50b3d98e7043012b24000011</div>
```

**So, what's the best way to do this?** Where do I go with scrapy? Or is there another python library better suited for this?

Feel free to comment, point me in a direction with code snips, to other SO questions/answers, contribute to github. What I'm trying to do is obviously beyond my experience at this point.

Comment: I think It will be hard to write scrapper without Python experience. You can ask for help at [ScraperWiki mail list](http://groups.google.com/group/scraperwiki). Also, someone already started work on [pettitions scrapper](https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/state_secession_petition_signatures/)

Comment: @reclosedev, thanks for the ideas. I posted on that list and looked at scraperwiki, too.

Answer (score 1):

The 'random link' looks like it has the form:

https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/signatures/more/*petitionid*/ *pagenum*/ *lastpetition*
where *petitionid* is static for a single petition, *pagenum* increments each time and *lastpetition* is returned each time from the request.

My usual approach would be to use the requests library to emulate a session for cookies and then work out what requests the browser is making.

```
import requests
s=requests.session()
url='http://httpbin.org/get'
params = {'cat':'Persian',
          'age':3,
          'name':'Furball'}             
s.get(url, params=params)
```

I'd pay particular attention to the following link:

`<a href="/petition/shut-down-tar-sands-project-utah-it-begins-and-reject-keystone-xl-pipeline/H1MQJGMW?page=2&amp;last=50b5a1f9ee140f227a00000b" class="load-next no-follow active" rel="50ae9207eab72aed25000003">Load Next 20 Signatures</a>`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully emulate Jquery/Javascript with Python.
[You could have a look on spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)
or on web-testing automation tools like Selenium , which can fully automate any browser actions.
Previous question on SO:
[How can Python work with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826627/how-can-python-work-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't want to use Selenium because that's what I already tried, automating a web browser, because the browser window grows to thousands of pages and crashes.