# Scraping advice on Crawling and info from Javascript onclick() function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, import.io

I've finally found a thread on newbie help on this subject but I am no way forward with resolving this issue, partly because I'm a newbie at programming :)

The thread is:
[Newbie: How to overcome Javascript "onclick" button to scrape web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421074/newbie-how-to-overcome-javascript-onclick-button-to-scrape-web-page/16421303#16421303?newreg=3ad1bff7281f44468c9a9071c8f2f446)

I have a similar issue. The site I would like to scrape from has lots of information of a lot of parts, but I would like to only scrape certain part information (company, part number, etc). I have two issues:

1. How to grab such information from this site without the need to put in search information? Use a Crawler?
2. A part number has most of the information on a page but there is on page Javascript 'onclick()' function, when it is clicked opens up a small window displaying information that, in addition to, I would like to scrape. How can I scrape the information in this additional window?

I'm using import.io but have been advised to switch to Selenium and PhantomJS. I would welcome other suggestions, and not too complicated (or instructions provided, which would be awesome!), of other tools. I would really appreciate if someone can help me overcome this issue or provide instructions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a newbie and you want to create a web crawler for data extraction then I would recommend [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) however, selenium webdriver is slower than [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) (a python framework for coding web crawlers)

As you have been advised to use selenium, I will only focus on selenium using python.

***For your first issue : "How to grab such information from this site"***

Suppose the website from which you want to extract data is [www.fundsupermart.co.in](https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/fundinfo/mutualfund-AXIS-BANKING-DEBT-FUND--GROWTH-AXS0077.html) (selected this to show how to handle new window pop ups)

using selenium you can crawl by writing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/fundinfo/mutualfund-AXIS-BANKING-DEBT-FUND--GROWTH-AXS0077.html')
```

This will open the firefox browser webdriver and will load the page of the link provided in the `get()` method

Now suppose if you want to extract a table then you can extract by using its tag_name, xpath or class_name by using functions provided by selenium. Like here if I want to extract table under **"Investment Objective"** :
[image]

Then for this I will:

`right click -> inspect element -> find the appropriate tag from console -> right click -> copy xpath`

Here I found that `<tbody>` tag was the one from which I can extract the table so I right clicked that and clicked on copy xpath so I got the xpath of that tag i.e. :

`xpath=/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/font/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody`

then, in the code add this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

Similarly you can extract other data from any website also see selenium's doc [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

***For you second issue : "How can I scrape the information in this additional window?"***

For clicking the link you can use `click()` function provided by selenium. Suppose here I want to click the link : `Click here for price history` then I will get the xpath(as done previously) and add line :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

I will open a new window like this :

[image]

Now to extract data from new window you will have to switch to new window which you can do by adding this line:

```
windows = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window(windows[1])
```

Now, by doing this I have switched the webdriver to the new window and now I can extract data as I did earlier and to close this window and switch back to original window just add :

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(windows[0])
```

This was a very basic and naive approach of web crawlers using selenium. The tutorial given [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) is really good and will help you a lot.