# scrapy crawl the click handle by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I want to scrapy this link

```
http://services.geospatial.org.tw/maploc/
```

I'd learned how to use scrapy to request a form

```
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formname=' ',
                                    formdata={ },    
                                    callback=self.parse)
```

But this is use javascript to control the click (`<input type="button" value="查詢" onclick="codeAddress()">`)
 It didn't have form
 how can I do to scrpay this link??
 Please help me, thank you

Comment: Have you tried using Selenium Webdriver ?

Comment: I know selenium.but it will take more time to crawl. SO I want to know is there any way scrapy can do it.

Comment: yeah performance could be an issue. On the other hand the code for dealing it with Selenium would be easy. By my knowledge scrapy alone is not able to interact with javascripts

Comment: You can inspect network activity in your favorite browser's Dev Tools panel, look at what HTTP requests are made when you click on that button. When I enter "taipei" for example, I can see that there's a GET request for `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4staipei&7sUS&9sen-US&callback=_xdc_._2e312p&token=46610`, which returns some Javascript data, with an object

Comment: so how to use get in scrapy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click a Button in Scrapy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682503/click-a-button-in-scrapy)