# Scraping react-id

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy in this [page](https://example.com.br/) to extract the phone number in the element:

```
sel = selector(response)
sel.xpath('.//*[@class="ProfileSimpleContact-item"]/span/span/text()').extract()
```

but this returns:

```
['(11) 98528-27...']
```

I want to get the full number (without "..."), which only appears with dynamic clicking a react id. How can I get it?

Comment: I see it is only generated when you click it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682503/click-a-button-in-scrapy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) as last option, it will cause that your spider be more expensive and complex.

Luckily, in your case you can use one of the `<script>` tags to get the required data.

First you need to get the correct `<script>` tag:

```
ans = response.xpath("//script[contains(text(),'telephone')]/text()").extract_first()
```

It gives you a `json` like this:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Cynthia Hóss Rocha",
    "description": "advogada há 15 anos.",
    "telephone": "(11) 985282712",
    "image": "imgs.jusbr.com/profiles/5368773/images/1419878998_standard.jpg",
    "jobTitle": "Advogado",
    "url": "https://cynthiahossrocha.jusbrasil.com.br",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "São Paulo (SP)",
        "streetAddress": "Rua Marconi, 131",
        "postalCode": "01047-000"
    }
}
```

To convert it into an object you need to `import json` and use `json.loads`:

```
json_ans = json.loads(ans)
```

Finally you only need to extract the required value:

```
phone = json_ans["telephone"]
```