# Is there a way to use multithreading with chromedriver?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver

i have a task where i need selenium automation to do multiple searches inputs, each has to open the browser do some interactions and close, i can do that one after the other , but i thought that if i implement multithreading on this project it would be alot faster,i tried to implement it but it never worked as expected
i did some searchs a read about queue and thread workers
but couldn't implement that either
so can i make a queue and only 4 Threads work at time ?
because i guess more than 4 browser would be alot. and would it be safe threaded ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python selenium multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475578/python-selenium-multiprocessing). Be sure to look at my answer to this which offers a much-needed improvement.The point is that if you have 4 threads and 20 tasks you want to run (20 URLs), you do not want to be opening and closing up 20 browsers but rather just 4 (one for each thread). This shows you how to reuse the browser for each new task (URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module `threading` and a function:

```py
import threading

def main():
   # your code to execute with Selenium

for _ in range(4):
   threading.Thread(tagret=main).start()
```

More than 4 browsers doing things at the same time could be indeed a lot, but it really depends on your PC and on how heavy the page is. You can always try out the code above with less threads and see how it goes.