# How can I run two(or more) selenium's webdrivers at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, webdriver, apply-async

I'm trying to run two(or more) selenium webdrivers with Python at the same time

I have so far tried using Python's Multiprocessing module, I have used it this way:

```
def _():
    sets = list()
    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(len(master)):
        driver = setProxy(proxy,f'Tread#{i+1}')
        sets.append(
            [f'Thread#{i+1}',
            driver,
            master[i]]
        )
    for i in range(len(sets)):
        pool.apply_async(enterPoint, args=(sets[i][0],sets[i][1],sets[i][2]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The function above calls `setProxy()` to get a driver instance with a proxy set to it, which works perfectly and opens a chromedriver `len(master)` amount of times and accesses a link to check the IP. The `sets` list is a list of lists that consist of 3 objects that are the Thread number, the driver which will run and a list with the data that the driver will use. Pool's `apply_async()` should run `enterPoint()` `len(sets)` of times, and the `args` are Thread number, driver and the data
Here's enterPoint code:

```
def enterPoint(thread,driver,accounts):
    print('I exist!')
    for account in accounts:
        cEEPE(thread,driver,account)
```

But the 'I exist' statement never gets printed out in the CLI I'm running the application at.
`cEEPE()` is where the magic happens. I've tested my code without applying multiprocessing to it and it works as it should.
I suspect there's a problem in Pool's `apply_async()` method, which I might have used it the wrong way.

Comment: When you go to [the duplicate answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475578/python-selenium-multiprocessing) make sure you look at my answer, which is an important refinement to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided in the question is in isolation, so its harder to comment on, but I would set about using this process given the problem described:

1. import `multiprocessing` & `selenium`
2. use `start` & `join` methods.

This would produce the two (or more) processes that you ask for.

```py
import multiprocessing
from selenium import webdriver

def open_browser(name):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    print(name, driver.title)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_browser, args=("Process-1",))
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=open_browser, args=("Process-2",))

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I plan on achieving is running two chromedrivers withing the same script at the same time, so I need a function to be executed twice without having to execute the script twice. Your code works as it should but it only opens the second webdriver when the first one is closed, I want two webdrivers opened and browsing the web at the same time.

Comment: It's worth noting that when running Selenium WebDriver with multiprocessing, you need to make sure that each process is running on a different port, otherwise it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the code above to work, here's how I fixed it:
instead of writing the `apply_async()` method like this:

```
pool.apply_async(enterPoint, args=(sets[i][0],sets[i][1],sets[i][2]))
```

here's how I wrote it:

```
pool.apply_async(enterPoint(sets[i][0],sets[i][1],sets[i][2]))
```

But still, this does not fix my issue since I would like enterPoint to run twice at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily with [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), which can multi-thread tests (Eg: `-n=3` for 3 threads), or even set a proxy server (`--proxy=USER:PASS@SERVER:PORT`)

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python`:

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__, "-n=3")

class GoogleTests(BaseCase):
    @parameterized.expand(
        [
            ["Download Python", "Download Python", "img.python-logo"],
            ["Wikipedia", "www.wikipedia.org", "img.central-featured-logo"],
            ["SeleniumBase.io Docs", "SeleniumBase", 'img[alt*="SeleniumB"]'],
        ]
    )
    def test_parameterized_google_search(self, search_key, expected_text, img):
        self.open("https://google.com/ncr")
        self.hide_elements("iframe")
        self.type('input[title="Search"]', search_key + "\n")
        self.assert_text(expected_text, "#search")
        self.click('a:contains("%s")' % expected_text)
        self.assert_element(img)
```

(This example uses parameterized to turn one test into three different ones.) You can also apply the multi-threading to multiple files, etc.