Working with mutiple tabs simultaneously using threads (Python + Selenium)
How to work with multiple tabs in one browser simultaneously using Python? Selenium have switch window function, but it does sequentially.
I have tried switch to other window, but it is a sequential process. #Python #Selenium

you can't do this... you need 1 thread per driver/browser pair.

Selenium just drives a browser like a user would. Can you work with multiple tabs simultaneously, or do you need to focus each one sequentially?

You are going to have to do thing sequentially unless you work with multi-processing (which can be difficult in python because of the GIL or overhead). If you want to work with multiple tabs in the same browser you can use:
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
This might help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475578/python-selenium-multiprocessing

But I want to do this simultaneously in the same window, is there a way? Lets suppose if I change language from Python to JavaScript?
