# Scraping attempt with javascript elements using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy

i am a newbie to scraping and selenium. The page which i want to scrape uses a js script on a button to get to the next page. I found part of a code ([Click a Button in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682503/click-a-button-in-scrapy)) on SO but i cant seem to make it work.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import scrapy

class chSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidypy'
    allowed_domains = ['117.145.177.252']
    start_urls = ['http://117.145.177.252/login.do?method=enterPdamccx']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self,response):

        self.driver.get('http://117.145.177.252/login.do?method=enterPdamccx')

        while True:
            try:
                next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/a')
                url = 'http://117.145.177.252/login.do?method=enterPdamccx'
                yield Request(url,callback=self.parse2)
                next.click()
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()

    def parse2(self,response):
        print('you are here!')
```

I recieve following error messages several times:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps you're not making it on the first driver.get() or the yield, skipping the click completely. Try clicking before yeild.

Answer (score 0):

That a has an onclick, so you would just do:

```
driver.execute_script('doMccx()')
```