# Can I use scrapy to click on button that has no href but has onclick property?

Tags: python, button, scrapy, onclick, screen-scraping

I'm kinda new with Scrapy and I've encountered a problem. I'm trying to extract information from this webpage that uses this type of buttons:

`<a id="" href="#" ... onclick="function()..."`

I've been looking for examples but all of them work with href. Is there a solution? Do I need to use other tools to do the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this by using `scrapy` but if you want to scrape these type of website then you may use [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). It is a great library for these javascript pages.

For more detail information about why `scrapy` doesn't work and why you should use `selenium` you may visit these link. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682503/click-a-button-in-scrapy) is similar to your question. [Selenium vs scrapy](https://stackshare.io/stackups/scrapy-vs-selenium). You may visit here : [Scraping Javascript Enabled Websites using Scrapy-Selenium](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scraping-javascript-enabled-websites-using-scrapy-selenium/)

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to migrate the code from Selenium because it is way too slow. But the site is full of js interactions. I've seen that there's a library called Splash that deals with the js. However, I haven't been successful on finding what I'm looking for. Thank you for your answer tho :)

Comment: I am not aware of `splash` sorry. I can't give you any explanation about it. I have to do my own research about it, learn basics and then only I would be able to write any further explanation. Which I am not interested right now. So, I wrote what I knew and what I found while doing research about your problems.

Comment: Yes! Don't worry :D As soon as I get more information about this I'll update this question with, hopefully, an answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "click" a button but you can monitor the network tab to see what request is being sent on click.
Take [this page](http://quotes.toscrape.com/login) for example. When you click the Login button, a POST request is sent. You can easily send POST requests using scrapy.
Here is a code snippet:

```
r = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'username': 'd','password':'x'})
yield(r)
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I answered you. The problem here is that is not a form, it's a simple button (navigates to another place in the site) that when I press it, it doesn't seem to have a get/post response in the network tab. However I've reached the conclusion that in the end, I would be building the same tool that I already have, only a bit more efficient by using Scrapy in terms of data extraction, which is not the problem and not the slowest part of the code. Thank you very much tho